# Fit drawable set to android:windowBackground

Tags: android, android-xml, splash-screen, android-drawable, android-theme

I'm trying to make a splash screen that shows before any inflation and I do this by setting a drawable to android:windowBackground in my SplashActivities theme like this:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

The drawable is displaying a fullscreen bitmap (got one for both landscape and portrait in land/port folders) and not an smaller image or icon and it  looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/dark_gray"/>

    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash_screen" android:gravity="center"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Since it's a fullscreen image I want it to fill out the screen without stretching, the same behavior as when you have an ImageView with adjustViewBounds is true and when the scaleType is set to fitCenter.

So to specify I am NOT looking for an layout or ImageView set up but a drawable that I can apply to the windowBackground. I'm stressing this because most search results I've found have been splash screens implemented after the app have started.

Comment: I tried also and could not find a solution.
android:width and android:height would help but this is only available on API 23+

Answer (score 0):

**There is no solution for this.**

I tried also and could not find a solution.
android:width and android:height would help but this is only available on API 23+

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<item
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawable="@drawable/yelo_logo" />
```

instead of bitmap.

It works on 8+ not on 5.0 though